# libnss3 package version update (document signing issue)

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, encryption

I am running EOS 5.1

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.1 Hera
Release:    5.1
Codename:   hera
```

I am currently experiencing a problem signing odt documents in LibreOffice.*
I have upgraded Libreoffice using a ppa, but this has not fixed my perceived issue. (6.0.7 --> 6.3.4)
My next step in troubleshooting is to update libnss3.

current version:

```
apt-cache show libnss3
Package: libnss3
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7
```

according to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?resolution=FIXED&classification=Components&query_format=advanced&product=NSS&target_milestone=3.36)
There were several bug fixes in 3.36 alone.  The current stable version is 3.45(?)

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could update this package?

*I can sign new documents using my p12 cert stored in ~/.pki/nssdb and everything is fine.  the problem occurs when I must sign a document that was previously signed by someone else, my signature shows as "invalid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the .deb package from [libnss3_3.45-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.45-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb)
. After that, you can use [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/) to install it.

Before installing the package:
`libnss3 is already the newest version (2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7).`

After installing it:

```
vlad@lenovo-y530:~$ apt list libnss3 -a
Listing... Done
libnss3/now 2:3.45-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,local]
libnss3/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.7 amd64
libnss3/bionic 2:3.35-2ubuntu2 amd64
```

Please let us know if this solves the signing issue.

Comment: what's eddy? can't I just use 
`dpkg -i libnss3_3.45-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

Comment: I was able to install the newer version of the nss libraries using dpkg.
`apt list libnss3
Listing... Done
libnss3/now 2:3.45-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,local]`
This however did not resolve my signing issue.

Comment: Eddy is just a simple GUI app used to install debs. Not everyone knows about dpkg or are comfortable using bash. Anyway, I'm glad I could help with your problem a bit. Now I recommend closing this question and it would be better to ask for help at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/, since your issue is not an elementary OS one.